# iOS, GTLFramework - how to fetch all videos from a channel using pageTokens

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

Here's my code for retrieving list of YouTube videos from a particular channel:

```
GTLServiceYouTube *service;
self.vidInfos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
service.APIKey = @"my-api-key";

GTLQueryYouTube *query1 = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsListWithPart:@"id,snippet"];
query1.playlistId = @"the-playlist-id-from-utube-channel";
query1.maxResults = 50;

[service executeQuery:query1 completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        GTLYouTubePlaylistItemListResponse *playlistItems = object;
        for (GTLYouTubePlaylistItem *playlistItem in playlistItems) {
            [self.vidInfos addObject:playlistItem];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];
```

And, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
GTLYouTubePlaylistItem *itemToDisplay = [self.vidInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = itemToDisplay.snippet.title;
```

The query accepts max 50 as the maximum result limit. But I need to display the entire list, which is about 250 videos.

How do i do it? I read about using `pageTokens`, but I couldn't find any sample or code on how to use `pageTokens`, where to get them and where to pass them?

Comment: I think, you need to get page-token and again pass it to the query to get next 50's list

Comment: how do i get pagetoken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `GTLYouTubeListResponse`, that you receive after making a query, have an `NSString` property that is called `nextPageToken`.
This property indicates the 'address' of the 'next page', in case you have several 'pages' of search results,
(Meaning, the amount of search results is higher than the amount you've set in the `maxResults` property, which, as you've said, have a 50 results limit)

So, using your question as an example of 250 results total, you have 5 search results 'pages' of 50 search results on each 'page'.

`GTLYouTubeQuery` have a corresponding `pageToken` property, which 'tells' the query what 'page' of the results you want to receive.

Could be another ways to achieve that, but this was just at the top of my head
and I think this is pretty simple and straightforward way of achieving this,
Anyway, the example below uses your code to demonstrate how this property can be used.

**IMPORTANT NOTE !!!**
In the code below, I'm 'looping' through **ALL** of the search results,
This is just for illustration purposes,
In your app, you would probably also want to create your own custom limit,
So if the user searches for a general keyword, that have TONS of results, you won't try to fetch them all which, among other disadvantages, will probably be more than he will ever read, make an unnecessary network and memory usage, and will 'hog' your google developer points (or whatever it is called, when it 'costs' you to make google API calls)

So, if we'll use your original code-

```
// First, make GTLServiceYouTube a property, so you could access it thru out your code  
@interface YourViewControllerName ()  
@property (nonatomic, strong) GTLServiceYouTube *service;  
@end  

// don't forget to still initialise it in your viewDidLoad
self.vidInfos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
service = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
service.APIKey = @"my-api-key";

GTLQueryYouTube *query1 = [GTLQueryYouTube queryForPlaylistItemsListWithPart:@"id,snippet"];
query1.playlistId = @"the-playlist-id-from-utube-channel";
query1.maxResults = 50;

// After you've created the query, we will pass it as a parameter to our method  
// that we will create below
[self makeYoutubeSearchWithQuery:query1];

// Here we create a new method that will actually make the query itself,  
// We do that, so it'll be simple to call a new search query, from within  
// our query's completion block
-(void)makeYoutubeSearchWithQuery:(GTLQueryYouTube *)query {  
    [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            GTLYouTubePlaylistItemListResponse *playlistItems = object;
            for (GTLYouTubePlaylistItem *playlistItem in playlistItems) {
                [self.vidInfos addObject:playlistItem];
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }  

        // Here we will check if our response, has a value in the nextPageToken  
        // property, meaning there are more search results 'pages'.  
        // If it is not nil, we will just set our query's pageToken property  
        // to be our response's nextPageToken, and will call this method  
        // again, but this time pass the 'modified' query, so we'll make a new  
        // search, with the same parameters as before, but that will ask the 'next'  
        // page of results for our search  
        // It is advised to add some sort of your own limit to the below if statement,  
        // such as '&& [self.vidInfos count] < 250'
        if(playlistItems.nextPageToken) {  
            query.pageToken = playlistItems.nextPageToken;  
            [self makeYoutubeSearchWithQuery:query];
        } else {  
            NSLog(@"No more pages");
        }
    }];  
}
```

Good luck mate.